# Copy DateListPlot ticks in ListLinePlot (for large data)

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, date-and-time, ticks

It is not very surprising that plotting a `PackedArray` is faster to plot than a list of pairs (date, value), nonetheless the plotting time may be prohibitive with `DateListPlot`.

The function `benchmark` below takes a size as an argument, and compute a list of points to plot in three different ways:

- `ListLinePlot` of `List` of pairs (real, real)
- `DateListPlot` of `List` of pairs (date, real)
- `DateListPlot` of `TimeSeries`

As you can see, `ListLinePlot` is much faster.

[image]

```
benchmark[n_] := Block[{y, t, t2, ts},
  y = RandomReal[{0, 10}, n];
  t = Sort@RandomReal[{UnixTime[], UnixTime[] + 10000}, n];
  t2 = FromUnixTime /@ t;
  ts = TimeSeries[Transpose@{t2, y}];
  
  {AbsoluteTiming@ListLinePlot[Transpose[{t, y}]], 
    AbsoluteTiming@DateListPlot[Transpose[{t2, y}]], 
    AbsoluteTiming@DateListPlot@ts}[[All, 1]]
]

nvals = 75*Range[60]^2;
tab = ParallelTable[benchmark[n], {n, nvals}];
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{nvals, #}] & /@ Transpose@tab, 
 PlotLabel -> "Timing vs Size", PlotLabels -> {"ListLinePlot", "DateListPlot", 
   "DateListPlot@TimeSeries"}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

In practice, waiting several seconds can be limiting, for example when plotting multiple curves with long time series  with a dynamic range selection.

In such cases, using `DateListPlot` is prohibitive, so I would like to use `ListLinePlot` instead. However, the date formatting is neat.

**Question** Is it possible to display dates on the $x$-axis with `ListLinePlot`, to mimick the rendering of `DateListPlot` while preserving an efficient timing?

Comment: It is not clear to me what question you are asking. I don't see any serious performance issues in your plot. All three timing results seem to be O[n]. Is there a real, practical problem with plotting 250000 dates taking 10 sec. rather than 2.

Comment: @m_goldberg I edited to ask a specific question. Yes, there a real practical problems where the timing difference has implications and that's how I discovered the timing different between the two (plotting 8 times series with 40000 points each).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the function `` System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks `` to generate date ticks. Its argument pattern is:

```
System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[{mindate, maxdate}, ndivisons] (* or *)

System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[{mindate, maxdate}, ndivisons, labelformat]
```

**Example:**

```
data1 = TimeSeries[{1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 11}, {"Jan 1, 2015"}];
data2 = TimeSeries[{5, 8, 9, 6, 2, 4, 7}, {"Jan 1, 2015"}];

DateListPlot[{data1, data2}, PlotLegends -> {"first", "second"}]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[{data1, data2}, PlotLegends -> {"first", "second"}, Joined -> True, 
 Ticks -> {System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[{##}, 5] &, Automatic}]
```

[image]

If you use `Frame -> True` or use a `PlotTheme` such as `"Detailed"` that adds a frame, then we need to use `FrameTicks` instead of `Ticks`:

```
ListPlot[{data1, data2}, PlotLegends -> {"first", "second"}, 
 Joined -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, 
  {System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[{##}, 5] &, Automatic}},
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

To align grid lines with date ticks, we can specify horizontal grids using `` System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks ``:

```
ListPlot[{data1, data2}, PlotLegends -> {"first", "second"}, 
 Joined -> True,
 GridLines -> {System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[{##}, 5] &, Automatic}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.4, 0.5], AbsoluteThickness[1], 
    AbsoluteDashing[{1, 2}]], 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, 
   {System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[{##}, 5] &, Automatic}},
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

[image]

FWIW, using `Graphics` + `GraphicsComplex` may be faster than `ListPlot`:

```
Graphics[GraphicsComplex[Join[data1["Path"], data2["Path"]], 
  {ColorData[97] @ 1, Line[Range @ data1["PathLength"]], 
   ColorData[97] @ 2, Line[data1["PathLength"] + Range @ data2["PathLength"]]}], 
 Axes -> True, 
 AxesOrigin -> {Min[#["FirstTime"] & /@ {data1, data2}], 0}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
 Ticks -> {System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[{##}, 5] &, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Do you know why some `PlotTheme`s (such as `Detailed` or `Scientific`) overwrites the ticks so your first solution no longer works? I see no conflicting options in `Charting``ResolvePlotTheme["Detailed", ListPlot]`, yet.

Comment: @anderstood, the two themes  both add frame; so we need to use `FrameTicks` instead of `Ticks`.

Comment: Would you know why data1 = Table[{UnixTime[{2021, 03, 04, 15} + {0, 0, 0, i}], 
    RandomReal[]}, {i, 0, 50}];
ListPlot[data1, Ticks -> {System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[{##}, 10] &, Automatic}]` wrongly shows data on 7th March? `data1[[-1, 1]] // FromUnixTime` returns correctly 6th March.

Comment: @anderstood, ``System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks`` interprets the dates as `AbsoluteTime`.